# Komodo Edit 9 - Delete Blank Lines (added by Fire FTP)

Tags: firefox, ftp, komodo, komodoedit, blank-line

Is there a way to mass delete blank lines in KOMODO EDIT 9? Please help...

When I upload / download files with FTP and edit them with KOMODO EDIT 9, there are always new blank lines added somehow.

I need to delete them, but one at a time takes too long and I have many files ...

Also, how do I prevent blank lines from being added??? I use FireFTP client (for convenience) ... and don't know how to solve this VERY annoying mistery

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Komodo offers functionality to automatically clean your file of whitespaces and similar whenever you save, to toggle this:

- Open Preferences
- Ensure "Show All Settings" is checked (bottom left)
- Navigate to "File Saving"
- Modify to your preferences
- Press OK, Save your file

Alternatively if you just want to use it once/on-demand you can use Code > Remove Trailing Whitespace.

Comment: that did not remove 100s of blank lines ... there is an option in Notepadd ++ to do this, but I'm on Mac, so cant use notepad ++

Comment: You probably checked "Only clean changed lines".